# Vimeo, jQuery and WordPress on finish event

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get the 'finish'-event working on vimeo video.
So when the video finishes I can execute a function.
The website is based off upon WordPress.
The page on WP has the following code:

```
<script src="froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="player" src="player.vimeo.com/video
/142350174?autoplay=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0"
 allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var iframe = $('#player')[0],
    player = $f(iframe),
    status = $('.status');

    player.addEvent('ready', function() {   
        console.log('ready');   
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
    });

    function onFinish(id) {
        console.log('video has ended');
    }
});
</script>
```

First I added the froogaloop script from Vimeo.
jQuery is already available, so I dont have to add that one.

The iframe tag I copied/pasted from Vimeos my vids.
I have added the id attribute.

The rest of the code is based on the following links:
https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api
http://jsfiddle.net/vy9kf0w5/3/

If I don't add the jQuery(document).ready line, I get a jQuery error.

I can't even get the ready event to run.

Am I missing something?
Thanks in advanced!

ps. I had to change the src of froogaloop and the src of the iframe because of the link amount restrictions.